# Cache busting @import css in Spring when using content version strategy

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot, caching

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/cachable-static-assets-with-spring-mvc) on using a content version strategy in spring for static assets. Everything works as intended except there is a corner case that I don't know how to fix:

My HTML has a `<link>` to a css file, `a.css`. If I look at the html returned by the server, I see that the link has been transformed to a-(md5).css, as it should. The problem I have is that `a.css` imports `b.css`. Spring is also properly updating the import from `@import '/css/b.css'` to `@import '/css/b-(md5).css'` The problem appears when I update `b.css`. Because the md5 of `a.css` is the same (the @import is to the static name), the browser is caching the request of `a-(md5).css`, which still points to the resolved `b-(old-md5).css` and I end up with the wrong styling

This sounds like a common problem. How can this be fixed?
Is it possible to tell the version strategy to compute the md5 *after* resolving links so that if the dependency's md5 changed, so would the dependent's md5?

This is my config

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    //content-based versioning and max caching
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .setCacheControl(MAX_CACHE_DURATION)
            .resourceChain(false)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());

    //no cache
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to solve this cleanly. My workaround was to disable caching for all css

```
        registry.addResourceHandler("/ui/css/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
            .resourceChain(false)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver());
```